# Bison reporting error mechanism can be overwritten?

Tags: bison

I have noticed that Bison uses a specific error message that is passed to `yyerror()` function through `yyreportSyntaxError()`. This is a function generated by using `glr.c`.

Is there a way I can modify the behavior of this function?

One solution is to modify the error message in `yyerror()`. But suppose I want to avoid this, could I instruct Bison to use my own function instead of `yyreportSyntaxError()`?

Comment: I am no Bison / Flex expert. But as far as the manual as well as the o'reilly Bison / Flex book goes, using `yyerror()` is the way to go. However, you can catch errors directly while parsing and provide your own error routine without using `yyerror()` at all if you use a lexer like flex anyways. You basically define a token which defines the error in your grammar and catch it with an error routine.

Answer (score 0):

([Comment converted to an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

@Bort wrote:

> I am no Bison / Flex expert. But as far as the manual as well as the o'reilly Bison / Flex book goes, using `yyerror()` is the way to go. However, you can catch errors directly while parsing and provide your own error routine without using `yyerror()` at all if you use a lexer like flex anyways. You basically define a token which defines the error in your grammar and catch it with an error routine.